# Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages

Tags: php, composer-php, zeromq, php-extension

Sorry for duplication of this question with another one. I can't solve my problem.

I am working on a project based on [`Ratchet`](http://socketo.me). I am trying to run the [`Push Integration`](http://socketo.me/docs/push) example. So, in order to run, I should use composer to get some dependencies. I make a composer.json file like below:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "MyApp": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "0.3.*",
        "react/zmq": "0.2.*|0.3.*"
    }
}
```

When I execute composer on it, below error occurrs:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - react/zmq v0.3.0 requires ext-zmq * -> the requested PHP extension zmq is missing from your system.
    - react/zmq v0.2.0 requires ext-zmq * -> the requested PHP extension zmq is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for react/zmq 0.2.*|0.3.* -> satisfiable by react/zmq[v0.2.0, v0.3.0].
```

Below you can find composer.json of `Ratchet` and `ZMQ`:

ZMQ:

```
{
    "name": "react/zmq",
    "description": "ZeroMQ bindings for React.",
    "keywords": ["zmq", "zeromq"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.4.0",
        "ext-zmq": "*",
        "evenement/evenement": "~2.0",
        "react/event-loop": "0.4.*"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "ext-pcntl": "*"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": { "React\\ZMQ": "src" }
    },
    "extra": {
        "branch-alias": {
            "dev-master": "0.4-dev"
        }
    }
}
```

Ratchet:

```
{
    "name": "cboden/ratchet"
  , "type": "library"
  , "description": "PHP WebSocket library"
  , "keywords": ["WebSockets", "Server", "Ratchet", "Sockets"]
  , "homepage": "http://socketo.me"
  , "license": "MIT"
  , "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Chris Boden"
          , "email": "cboden@gmail.com"
          , "role": "Developer"
        }
    ]
  , "support": {
        "forum": "https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ratchet-php"
      , "issues": "https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet/issues"
      , "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.org/reactphp"
    }
  , "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Ratchet": "src"
        }
    }
  , "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.9"
      , "react/socket": "0.3.*|0.4.*"
      , "guzzle/http": "~3.6"
      , "symfony/http-foundation": "~2.2"
      , "symfony/routing": "~2.2"
    }
}
```

What is wrong? Please give me a solution. 
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 19):

Ok, here we go...

You must have ZMQ and ZMQ binding installed previously in operation system.
The following exemples is based on Debian Linux  but it should work in other OS.

First:
Installing 0MQ:
Go to http://zeromq.org/area:download and choose a package according your OS, in my case I've choosed
POSIX tarball Stable Release 4.0.4.

```
~$ tar -xvf zeromq-4.0.4.tar
~$ cd zeromq-4.0.4
~$ ./configure
~$ make
~$ sudo make install
```

Ok, we just have installed ZMQ now need install zmq php binding...
Make sure you having php-dev and php pear installed. If no:

```
~$ sudo apt-get install php5-dev php-pear
~$ sudo pecl install zmq-beta
```

Ok, we have now ZMQ and php binding (ext-php) installed but we should add "extension=zmq.so" (Or extension=php_zmq.dll on windows) to php.ini:
In my case:

```
~$ sudo nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini
```

**NOTE:** If PHP version is 5.4.x (or 5.4+, but I haven't tested yet...) you will need to add a zmq.ini file in /etc/php5/conf.d and put "extension=zmq.so":

```
~$ sudo nano /etc/php5/conf.d/20-zmq.ini
```

Reloadind HTTP server (in my case apache):

```
~$  sudo service apache2 reload
```

WOW!!! Now we gonna to update composer requirements:

```
~$ composer --verbose update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  - Installing react/zmq (v0.3.0)
    Downloading: 100%         
    Extracting archive

Writing lock file
Generating autoload files
```

Answer (score 11):

If you are still getting the same error even after following the above answer then it might be because of incorrect `php.ini` used usually by `composer`.
You have to update the ini of `CLI PHP` also.

If you run the command `php --ini` from inside your terminal then you should see something like following:

[image]

This `.ini` meant for different usage than `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`. So, update that `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini` and add `extension=zmq.so` in it, if you think you already installed the extension following a correct workflow.

Hope you will get rid off that `the requested PHP extension zmq is missing` error while using composer installation.

Comment: You are a god among gods!!! That was all I needed after a half hour of trying to figure out what the heck was wrong. Thank you sooooo much.

Comment: Pleasure & happy to hear that :)

Comment: Yes! finally it all works. thanks for the extra tip!

Comment: I am not getting the cli list of php ini file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Xampp on windows, then follow these steps

1. Download all dll here http://pecl.php.net/package/zmq to your matching OS.
   Make sure you got the right one (x86 or x64) and that it is either thread safe or non-      thread safe. How would you know? Time to play DLL roulette.
2. Copy `libzmq.dll` to your `xampp/php/`
3. Copy `php_zmq.dll` to your php extension directory (eg. `xampp/php/ext/`)
4. Then add this to your php.ini `extension=php_zmq.dll`